# AJAX issue get values for query

Tags: php, ajax

I am using the following code to populate information on a page, when I click a button. The problem is that the link that I use (dezelfdeluchtvaartmaatschappij.php, when I click on the button, the page should query based on the parent page. The parent page is using this string:

index.php clickable link, produces vlucht.php?:

```
. '<a href="/vluchtgegevens/vlucht.php?id=' . $row['gegevenID'] . '&vid=' .     
$row['vertrekluchthaven'] . '&aid=' .$row['aankomstID'] .'&lvid=' . $row['lvmid'] .    
'&tid=' .$row['toestelID'] .'&inid='.$row['inschrijvingnmr'].'"> ' .
```

On the vlucht.php page, the script that I have is:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","vluchtinfo/hetzelfdevliegroute.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

The page, hetzelfdevliegroute.php is looking for the following as part of its query:

```
$vertrek = $_GET['vid'];
$aankomst = $_GET['aid'];
```

How does one pass the variables (vid & aid) to this page using the above function code:

My button code is:

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">hetzelfde vliegroute</button>
<div id="myDiv">&nbsp;</div>
```

Can I somehow say in my function:

```
"vluchtinfo/hetzelfdevliegroute.php?vid='.$row['vid'].'&aid='.$row['aid'].'"
```

Lastly, how would I do this to have multiple "pages" be available. So I have 4 or 5 buttons which would call different pages with different queries. I'm starting small or going bigger, so I can deal with just one response now and check again after I've learned more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var qs = location.search.split('&');
var params = {};
for ( var i = 0, l = qs.length; i < l; ++i ) {
    var parts = qs[i].split('=');
    params[parts[0]] = parts[1] || null;
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","vluchtinfo/hetzelfdevliegroute.php?vid=" + params['vid'] + '&aid=' + params['aid'],true);
```

This will get the querystring on the current page and parse it into the `params` object, then you can use it just like `$rows`.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I *really* appreciate your help on this!!!